# For right clicking, are ctrl-click and two-finger-tapping used exchangeably?

Tags: macos, trackpad

For right clicking, there are two ways when using the trackpad

- <kbd>Control</kbd>-click, i.e. tapping the trackpad while pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> key
- two-finger-tapping

Can they be used exchangeably?

If not, when to use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can be used interchangeably. The two-finger tap is a shortcut employed by OS X for more convenience / accessibility, however, it has exactly the same function as the <kbd>control</kbd>-click.

Comment: thanks.  in guest Ubuntu via virtualbox, right-clicking by tapping the right region of the trackpad doesn't do anything, while two-finger tapping does work like right-clicking in PC. I am not sure if keystrokes in guest Ubuntu should be the same as in Ubuntu directly installed on a computer, or same as in OS X. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242407/are-the-keystrokes-under-guest-ubuntu-via-virtualbox-supposed-to-be-the-same-in

Comment: @Tim I will look at your other question – meanwhile, if this answer helped you, please mark it as [accepted](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

In most apps, macOS treats <kbd>Control</kbd>-click the same as a right-click. However, some programs such as games and virtual machines listen to the keyboard not as a series of keystrokes but as whether each key is held down at each moment. These programs will receive the <kbd>Control</kbd> keypress and the left-click separately, without macOS transforming them into a right-click.

So feel free to use <kbd>Control</kbd>-click in most places if that’s easier for you. However, when playing games or using a VM you might have to use the two-finger click for the program to recognize it.